# Control webBrowser no carga

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Vereis tengo un webBroser al que le paso una url tal que así:

```
public Marcador()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();       
    }
public void playGol(String url)
    {          
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    }
```

Cuando llamo al metodo `playGol()` desde otro form el `webBroser1` no me muestra nada, pantalla en blanco, sin embargo si coloco la sentencia: `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://---");` en el constructor me carga correctamente la web, ¿Alguién sabe por que pasa? (Al parametro URL le llega bien la dirección de la web)

Otra cosa es que intento que abra un SWF y lo que me hace es abrirme el Chrome y descargarme el archivo, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me abra el `webBroser` y no el chrome y me muestre ( no descargar ) el SWF?

Gracias anticipadas

Edito: Lo llamo desde otro formulario:

```
private void btnGol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
Marcador marcador = new Marcador();
 marcador.playGol(@"C:\gol2.swf"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé cómo llamas al `Form` desde el otro, pero imaginando que tienes alguna clase global para ello:

Clase `AdministradorDeForms`, se encarga de manejar tus formularios en el programa:

```
public class AdministradorDeForms
{
    public Form1 FormConWebBrowser; 
    public Form2 FormQueLoLlama;

    public AdministradorDeForms()
    {
        FormConWebBrowser = new Form1(this); // Ambos apuntan hacia esta instancia
        FormQueLoLlama = new Form2(this);    // para navegar.
        FormConWebBrowser.Show();            // Muestra el form con el webBrowser
    }
}
```

Form1 (El `Form` que tiene el `WebBrowser`):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private AdministradorDeForms Admin;
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }
    public Form1(AdministradorDeForms frm) { InitializeComponent(); Admin = frm; }
    public void playGol(string Url)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(Url);
        // Solo por si acaso, actualizamos el form y el webBrowser.
        webBrowser1.Refresh(); this.Refresh();
    }
    // Otras implementaciones y eventos...
}
```

Form2 (El `Form` que vá a llamar a `Form1` para navegar):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private AdministradorDeForms Admin;
    public Form2() { InitializeComponent(); }
    public Form2(AdministradorDeForms frm) { InitializeComponent(); Admin = frm; }

    private void AlgunObjeto_Accion(...)
    {
        // Supongamos que obtenemos la url de cualquier otro lugar, yo pondré un string 
        string url = "https://google.com/";
        // Llamamos al administrador para navegar en el otro form:
        Admin.FormConWebBrowser.playGol(url); // Debería de funcionar :D
    }
    // Otras implementaciones y eventos...
}
```

En el `AlgunObjeto_Accion(...)` debes cambiar el nombre y sus parametros de evento por el del objeto que vá a ejecutar la navegación en el otro `Form` y la clase `AdministradorDeForms` la instancias al inicio del programa, en el `void Main()` de tu aplicación.

---

**EDIT**: Para lo que implementas, estás llamando una nueva instancia desde un botón, es mejor hacer esto siguiente:

Imaginemos que así tienes tu form `Marcador`:

```
// Form marcador
public partial class Marcador : Form
{
    private string URL; // Creamos un campo url para pasarlo por el inicializador
    public Marcador() { InitializeComponent(); } 
    public Marcador(string url) { InitializeComponent(); URL = url; }
    private void Marcador_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(URL); // Al mostrar el formulario, entonces sale esto!
        webBrowser1.Refresh(); // Por si acaso.
    }
}
```

Y en este `Form` tienes el botón:

```
// Form que llama al marcador con el botón:
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void btnGol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Al hacer click en el botón btnGol, se crea una nueva instancia
        // con la URL
        Marcador marcador = new Marcador(@"C:\gol2.swf"); 
        marcador.Show(); // Y se muestra el form....
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo llamo desde otro formulario:                                                      private void btnGol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Marcador marcador = new Marcador();
           marcador.playGol(@"C:\gol2.swf");
        }

Comment: Considera agregar esa información editando la pregunta, de todas formas, mira el *edit*, @FranPino